# how to implement angularjs typeahead when user types '@' only

Tags: angularjs

When user types '@' in the textarea, i want to display the some values as suggestions.
I used typeahead directive, but it is showing the suggestions for the macthing value entered in the textarea. I want to show only when user types '@'.
Please sugeest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had to create such a typeahead for '@@'.

Maybe use [Bootstrap UI Typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). You just need to create your own filter and check if the input contains your '@'.

If you want to completely create it by yourself, than you need a watcher on the ngModel variable. If user does input stg, check for the @ and show/hide your typeahead.

The html must be $compiled with the scope and injected after your textfield.

```
var template = angular.element(
          '<ul class="dropdown-menu typeahead">' +
          '<li data-ng-repeat="match in arrMatches = (matches | filter:matchTypeAheadFilter)" ng-class="{\'active\':selectedMatch==match}" >' +
          '<a data-ng-bind="match" data-ng-click="injectMatch(match);"></a>' +
          '</li >' +
          '</ul>');

$compile(template.contents())(scope);
$(element).after(template);
```

Now this template is the typeahead container.

Every `li` represents a match.

```
scope.$watch("ngModel", function (newValue,oldValue)
{
   if(newValue.indexOf('@') > -1)
    scope.openTypeAhead(newValue);
});
```

In the `openTypeAhead` you need to logic to show the container, apply click + key events.

```
scope.openTypeAhead = function(inputValue){            
          var firstTimeOpen = $(template).css("display") == "none";
          if(firstTimeOpen)
          {
            $(element).keydown(keyEvents);
            $(document).click(onClick);
          }

          $(template).show(); //show typeahead

          scope.matches = //load your matches
        }else{
          scope.hideTypeAhead();
        }
      };
```

I'd suggest to your the framework. Because this is not simply done.

Comment: Thank you Konstantin Krass! I appreciate your time. I am going ahead with bootstrap UI typeahead directive with some customization